# How to integrate a usb signature pad with my UWP application?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, electronic-signature

In my UWP application i have to show the signature which is captured by a usb connected signature pad(model Scriptel - ST1501).

After some research I have found that this model uses EasyScript Device Interface.
But i don't understand how to integrate this with my application project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [Scriptel's website](http://scriptel.com/developers/easyscript/), it does have C# APIs and software libraries support for EasyScript. However, I'm not sure if this can be used in UWP. You can download its [Development Package](http://services.scriptel.com/releases/scriptouch-easyscript/easyscript-api) and have a try.

Comment: I am trying it and it seems like their code supports only WinForm appications.